# UFW/IPTables: after setting default outgoing deny, and port 80 outgoing allow, curl still doesn't work

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, ufw

With UFW, I disabled all outgoing and ingoing traffic by default. However, I do allow port 80 in and out:

1. `sudo ufw default deny incoming` (deny all incoming)
2. `sudo ufw default deny outgoing` (deny all outgoing)
3. `sudo ufw allow in 80/tcp` (accept all incoming tcp from port 80)
4. `sudo ufw allow out 80/tcp` (accept all outgoing tcp to port 80)

Yet, the following commands don't seem to work. Could anyone tell me why?

```
mainuser@saturn101:~/apps/mongodb$ curl http://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.4-rc1.tgz > mongodb-2.0.4-rc1.tgz

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'fastdl.mongodb.org'
```

And,

```
ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

And,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't enable DNS traffic (TCP/UDP outgoing, port 53) and UDP 1024-65535 outgoing (also required for DNS.

Comment: Excellent, apt-get update seems to be working without UDP 1024-65535 outgoing though. When is this really necessary?

Comment: FYI, I have posted a [follow up question](http://serverfault.com/questions/370743/ufw-iptables-how-to-securely-allow-authenticated-git-access-with-github)

Comment: Outgoing to port 53 UDP and TCP is sufficient for DNS.  Restricting the source to 1024-65535 for this rule is optional.

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax would be

```
sudo ufw allow out to any port 53
```

This resolves problem with DNS